# read xml in python

Tags: python, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <LoginResult>true</LoginResult>
            <aSessionID>AF-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-12-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-CA</aSessionID>
        </LoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This xml  format coming form sope api i want to read xml aSessionID form this. Please help me to do this in python

Comment: see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <LoginResult>true</LoginResult>
            <aSessionID>AF-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-12-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-CA</aSessionID>
            <aSessionID>54F-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-45-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-65</aSessionID>
        </LoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and then:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("list_test.xml")
sessionList = doc.getElementsByTagName('aSessionID')

for sess in sessionList:
    print(sess.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
AF-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-12-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-CA
54F-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-45-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-65
```

**EDIT**:

To read the `xml` from a `string` rather than the file, you may use:

```
minidom.parseString(xml_str)
```

Hence:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml_str = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <LoginResult>true</LoginResult>
            <aSessionID>AF-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-12-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-CA</aSessionID>
            <aSessionID>54F-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-45-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-65</aSessionID>
        </LoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''
doc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)
sessionList = doc.getElementsByTagName('aSessionID')

for sess in sessionList:
    print(sess.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
AF-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-12-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-CA
54F-6A-51-FD-E6-8D-C8-45-AB-7E-C1-BD-50-7A-43-D0-AA-27-15-65
```

Comment: If this xml not in file, it is string then how can i do this?