# xml read in python with loop from soap request

Tags: python, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <DownloadDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
           <DownloadDataResult>
           <?xml version= "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
            <SkynetExchange>
                <MasterManifests>
                    <MasterManifest>
                        <Id>200044923</Id>
                        <OriginStation>DHX</OriginStation>
                        <MastermanifestPrefix>0222</MastermanifestPrefix>
                        <MastermanifestNumber>1074680</MastermanifestNumber>
                        <DateofManifest>2019-03-04 13:25:27</DateofManifest>
                        <FlightNumber>20190304</FlightNumber>
                        <MAWB>20190304</MAWB>
                        <SUBMAWB>PO TEST MANIFEST</SUBMAWB>
                        <ToStation>SA5</ToStation>
                        <TotalBags>1</TotalBags>
                        <TotalWeight>1.500</TotalWeight>
                        <PrealertInstructions></PrealertInstructions>
                        <MasterManifestStatus>CLS</MasterManifestStatus>
                    </MasterManifest>
                    <MasterManifest>
                        <Id>434324343</Id>
                        <OriginStation>DSDHX</OriginStation>
                        <MastermanifestPrefix>0s222</MastermanifestPrefix>
                        <MastermanifestNumber>32354</MastermanifestNumber>
                        <DateofManifest>2018-03-04 13:25:27</DateofManifest>
                        <FlightNumber>12212</FlightNumber>
                        <MAWB>afsd</MAWB>
                        <SUBMAWB>OP TEST MANIFEST</SUBMAWB>
                        <ToStation>SA5</ToStation>
                        <TotalBags>1</TotalBags>
                        <TotalWeight>1.500</TotalWeight>
                        <PrealertInstructions></PrealertInstructions>
                        <MasterManifestStatus>CLS</MasterManifestStatus>
                    </MasterManifest>
                </MasterManifests>
            </SkynetExchange>
        </DownloadDataResult>
    </DownloadDataResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have this xml and i want to run loop on MasterManifests data which have multiple MasterManifest tag. I want to read every tag value like id, OriginStation etc etc

Please help me

Comment: Again, a string or a file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read xml in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038595/read-xml-in-python)

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Not a dupe, since it has a different  requirement.

Answer (score 0):

list_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <DownloadDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
           <DownloadDataResult>
            <SkynetExchange>
                <MasterManifests>
                    <MasterManifest>
                        <Id>200044923</Id>
                        <OriginStation>DHX</OriginStation>
                        <MastermanifestPrefix>0222</MastermanifestPrefix>
                        <MastermanifestNumber>1074680</MastermanifestNumber>
                        <DateofManifest>2019-03-04 13:25:27</DateofManifest>
                        <FlightNumber>20190304</FlightNumber>
                        <MAWB>20190304</MAWB>
                        <SUBMAWB>PO TEST MANIFEST</SUBMAWB>
                        <ToStation>SA5</ToStation>
                        <TotalBags>1</TotalBags>
                        <TotalWeight>1.500</TotalWeight>
                        <PrealertInstructions> </PrealertInstructions>
                        <MasterManifestStatus>CLS</MasterManifestStatus>
                    </MasterManifest>
                    <MasterManifest>
                        <Id>434324343</Id>
                        <OriginStation>DSDHX</OriginStation>
                        <MastermanifestPrefix>0s222</MastermanifestPrefix>
                        <MastermanifestNumber>32354</MastermanifestNumber>
                        <DateofManifest>2018-03-04 13:25:27</DateofManifest>
                        <FlightNumber>12212</FlightNumber>
                        <MAWB>afsd</MAWB>
                        <SUBMAWB>OP TEST MANIFEST</SUBMAWB>
                        <ToStation>SA5</ToStation>
                        <TotalBags>1</TotalBags>
                        <TotalWeight>1.500</TotalWeight>
                        <PrealertInstructions> </PrealertInstructions>
                        <MasterManifestStatus>CLS</MasterManifestStatus>
                    </MasterManifest>
                </MasterManifests>
            </SkynetExchange>
        </DownloadDataResult>
    </DownloadDataResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and then:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as md

root = md.parse('list_test.xml')
from xml.dom.minidom import Node
Manifests = root.getElementsByTagName('MasterManifest')
for elem in Manifests:
    try:
        for x in elem.childNodes:
            if x.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                 print(x.tagName, ": ", x.childNodes[0].data)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Id :  200044923
OriginStation :  DHX
MastermanifestPrefix :  0222
MastermanifestNumber :  1074680
DateofManifest :  2019-03-04 13:25:27
FlightNumber :  20190304
MAWB :  20190304
SUBMAWB :  PO TEST MANIFEST
ToStation :  SA5
TotalBags :  1
TotalWeight :  1.500
PrealertInstructions :   
MasterManifestStatus :  CLS


Id :  434324343
OriginStation :  DSDHX
MastermanifestPrefix :  0s222
MastermanifestNumber :  32354
DateofManifest :  2018-03-04 13:25:27
FlightNumber :  12212
MAWB :  afsd
SUBMAWB :  OP TEST MANIFEST
ToStation :  SA5
TotalBags :  1
TotalWeight :  1.500
PrealertInstructions :   
MasterManifestStatus :  CLS
```